# MySQL query painfully slow on large data

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm no MySQL whiz but I get it, I have just inherited a pretty large table (600,000 rows and around 90 columns (Please kill me...)) and I have a smaller table that I've created to link it with a categories table.

I'm trying to query said table with a left join so I have both sets of data in one object but it runs terribly slow and I'm not hot enough to sort it out; I'd really appreciate a little guidance and explanation as to why it's so slow.

```
SELECT 
    `products`.`Product_number`,
    `products`.`Price`,
    `products`.`Previous_Price_1`,
    `products`.`Previous_Price_2`,
    `products`.`Product_number`,
    `products`.`AverageOverallRating`,
    `products`.`Name`,
    `products`.`Brand_description`
FROM `product_categories`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `products`
ON `products`.`product_id`= `product_categories`.`product_id`
WHERE COALESCE(product_categories.cat4, product_categories.cat3,
product_categories.cat2, product_categories.cat1) = '123456'
AND `product_categories`.`product_id` != 0
```

The two tables are MyISAM, the products table has indexing on Product_number and Brand_Description and the product_categories table has a unique index on all columns combined; if this info is of any help at all.

Having inherited this system I need to get this working asap before I nuke it and do it properly so any help right now will earn you my utmost respect!

[Edit]
Here is the output of the explain extended:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | product_categories | index | NULL          | cat1 | 23      | NULL | 1224419 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | products           | ALL   | Product_id    | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  512376 |   100.00 |                          |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: did you look at explain result? Add EXPLAIN keyword before SELECT and share it.

Comment: Ahh that's a good idea, yeah I tried using explain (that's why it's ann left outer join instead of left/inner join) [ edit] that's in now buddy!

Comment: You might want to add `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` output instead.

Comment: @btiernay that's been updated, was the only difference the filtered field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of your query seems to be "find all products that have the category '123456'."  Is that correct?

`COALESCE` is an extraordinarily expensive function to use in a `WHERE` statement, because it operates on index-hostile NULL values.  Your explain result shows that your query is not being very selective on your product_categories table.  In MySQL you need to avoid functions in WHERE statements altogether if you want to exploit indexes to make your queries fast.

The thing someone else said about 90-column tables being harmful is also true. But you're stuck with it, so let's just deal with it.

Can we rework your query to get rid of the function-based `WHERE`?  Let's try this.

```
SELECT  /* some columns from the products table */
  FROM products
 WHERE product_id IN 
 (
     SELECT DISTINCT product_id 
                FROM product_categories
               WHERE product_id <> 0
                 AND (   cat1='123456'
                      OR cat2='123456'
                      OR cat3='123456'
                      OR cat4='123456')
 )
```

For this to work fast you're going to need to create separate indexes on your four cat columns.  The composite unique index ("on all columns combined") is not going to help you.  It still may not be so good.

A better solution might be FULLTEXT searching IN BOOLEAN MODE. You're working with the MyISAM access method so this is possible. It's definitely worth a try. It could be very fast indeed.

```
SELECT  /* some columns from the products table */
  FROM products
 WHERE product_id IN 
 (
     SELECT product_id 
       FROM product_categories
      WHERE MATCH(cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4) 
            AGAINST('123456' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        AND product_id <> 0

 )
```

For this to work fast you're going to need to create a FULLTEXT index like so.

```
 CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX cat_lookup 
                    ON product_categories (cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4)
```

Note that neither of these suggested queries produce precisely the same results as your `COALESCE` query. The way your `COALESCE` query is set up, some combinations won't match it that will match these queries. For example.

```
    cat1     cat2     cat3     cat4   
  123451   123453   123455   123456      matches your and my queries
  123456   123455   123454   123452      matches my queries but not yours
```

But it's likely that my queries will produce a useful list of products, even if it has a few more items in yours.

You can debug this stuff by just working with the inner queries on product_categories.

Comment: This sped it up but it's still taking a very long time to return result-set's over 500 rows, is there anything else I could do short of restructuring the database? Also, it was my understanding that COALESCE was a first non-null value in the list function?

Comment: Although both executed separately are very fast :/

Comment: COALESCE does stuff with NULL values. NULL value processing is easy enough unless it appears in a WHERE statement.  I don't understand you when you write "although both executed separately are very fast."

Comment: I was trying to work out which of the two queries (the main or the sub-query) was running slow but they both ran independently incredibly fast but in conjunction took 5-6 minutes.

Comment: You need an index on products.product_id, I believe. You need to be able to pull rows from that table fast after you've figured out the ones you want from the inner query.

Comment: Thanks Ollie, Although I've not actually used this solution (I've used a truly horrible hacky way with php to do it in a matter of seconds) this was by far the best result I've had; thank you for your time and advice.

Answer (score 3):

### Optimize Table

To establish a baseline, I would first recommend running an [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html) command on both tables. Please note that this might take some time. From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html):

> `OPTIMIZE TABLE` should be used if you have deleted a large part of a
>   table or if you have made many changes to a table with variable-length
>   rows (tables that have `VARCHAR, VARBINARY, BLOB`, or `TEXT` columns).
>   Deleted rows are maintained in a linked list and subsequent `INSERT`
>   operations reuse old row positions. You can use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to
>   reclaim the unused space and to defragment the data file. After
>   extensive changes to a table, **this statement may also improve
>   performance of statements that use the table, sometimes significantly.**
>
> [...]
>
> For MyISAM tables, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` works as follows:
>
> 1. If the table has deleted or split rows, repair the table.
> 2. If the index pages are not sorted, sort them.
> 3. If the table's statistics are not up to date (and the repair could not be accomplished by sorting the index), update them.

### Indexing

If space and index management isn't a concern, you can try adding a [composite index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on

```
product_categories.cat4, product_categories.cat3, product_categories.cat2, product_categories.cat1
```

This would be advised if you use a leftmost subset of these columns **often** in your queries. The query plan indicates that it can use the `cat1` index of `product_categories`. This most likely only includes the `cat1` column. By adding all four category columns to an index, it can more efficiently seek to the desired row. From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html):

> MySQL can use multiple-column indexes for queries that test all the
>   columns in the index, or queries that test just the first column, the
>   first two columns, the first three columns, and so on. If you specify
>   the columns in the right order in the index definition, **a single
>   composite index can speed up several kinds of queries on the same**
>   table.

### Structure

Furthermore, given that your table has **90 columns** you should also be aware that [a wider table can lead to slower query performance](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/09/why-mysql-could-be-slow-with-large-tables/). You may want to consider [Vertically Partitioning](http://apheliondynamics.com/blog/2010/02/11/database-optimization-vertical-partitioning-in-mysql/) your table into multiple tables:

> Having too many columns can bloat your record size, which in turn
>   results in more memory blocks being read in and out of memory causing
>   higher I/O. This can hurt performance. One way to combat this is to
>   split your tables into smaller more independent tables with smaller
>   cardinalities than the original. This should now allow for a better
>   Blocking Factor (as defined above) which means **less I/O and faster
>   performance**. This process of breaking apart the table like this is a
>   called a *Vertical Partition*.

Comment: I'm not sure what a composite index is so I don't just want to add it, what will it do? This is the only occasion where I must have both sets of data at the same time so again I'm not totally ok with adding an index for a single benefit..

Comment: Thanks for editing, I will give those links a read when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange. Does the table `product_categories` indeed have a `product_id` column? Shouldn't the `from` and `where` clauses be like this:

```
FROM `product_categories` pc 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `products` p ON p.category_id = pc.id
WHERE 
    COALESCE(product_categories.cat4, product_categories.cat3,product_categories.cat2, product_categories.cat1) = '123456'
    AND pc.id != 0
```

Comment: Yes the product_category table has a product id, I will investigate the from and where when I get back have headed out for an hour or so for church.