# When comparing current row with previous row the query is too slow

Tags: mysql, performance, join, compare, row

When subtracting the previous row from the current row the query is too slow, is there a more efficient way to do this?
I am trying to create a data filter which has the capacity to highlight events which occur sequentially to those that do not. I have a table of machine operational data 'source' which is ordered chronologically. Using a WHERE clause I filter out the data which is of less relevance to this particular analysis. The remaining data is inserted into a new table 'filtered'. Using the inserted ID numbers from 'source' I compare each row with its proceeding row to find the difference in value – if the difference is 1 then then the events have occurred in sequence and if the difference is null then they have not. My problem is with the length of time it takes to compare a row with the previous row. I have reduced my data volume to just 2.5% (275000 rows) of what it full volume will be and the query takes 3012 seconds according to the MySQL Workbench action output. I have experimented with structuring the query differently but ultimately have reached dead ends. So my question is –  Is there a more efficient way to compare a row with its previous row ?

OK – here are some more details.

```
/*First I create the table for the filtered data */
drop table if exists filtered_dta;
create table filtered_dta
 ( 
 ID         int (11)        not null        auto_increment,
 IDx1       int (11),
 primary key (ID)
 );
```

/*Then I insert the filtered data*/

```
insert into filtered_dta (IDx1)
      select seq from source
            WHERE   range_value < -1.75
            and     range_value > -5 ;

                   /* Then I compare each row with its previous */

                    select              t1.ID, t1.IDx1,(t1.IDx1-t2.IDx1) 
                    as                  seq_value
                    from                filtered_dta t1 
                    left outer join     filtered_dta t2 
                    on                  t1.IDx1 = t2.IDx1+1
                    order by IDx1
                    ;
```

Here are sample tables.

```
Table - filtered_dta                  Results

   | ID | IDx1 |              | ID | IDx1 | seq_value |
     1     3                    1     3       null
     2     4                    2     4        1
     3     7                    3     7       null
     4    12                    4    12       null
     5    13                    5    13        1
     6    14                    6    14        1
```

A full data set from the source table is expected to be between 3 and 10 million rows. The database will create and use about 50 tables. This database is being used as a back end engine for simulation software which does not have the capacity to process this amount of data and give an appropriate analysis of the system which the data represents. 
I have spent some time on the issue and have come across the following; 
It may be possible that the find_seq table is creates with myISAM and requires converting to an innoDB table. I tried to set the default engine to innoDB but seen no noticeable differences.
This question was similar in its problem of a slow query [MySQL query painfully slow on large data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884263/mysql-query-painfully-slow-on-large-data) - but its issue lay in having a function in a where clause – from my action output I can see the where clause is not too slow. 
I would appreciate any input anyone may have on this. Also I am not a proficient user of MySQL so if possible give details.
Kind regards.

Comment: An index on `filtered_dta`'s `IDx1` may help; but I am not sure how much with the `+1` operation in the join.

Comment: Thanks Uueerdo I added the Index and found the query ran 6%  faster. Although alone it doesn't bring down the query time by a significant enough margin.

Comment: @Uueerdo - good.  But change it to `t2.IDx1 = t1.IDx1+1` because of the `LEFT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this template to identify sequential "islands" without a self-join:

```
SELECT @island := @island + IF(seqId <> @lastSeqId + 1, 1, 0) AS island
, orderQ.[fieldsYouWant]
, @lastSeqId := seqId
FROM (
   SELECT [fieldsYouWant], [sequentialIdentifier] AS seqId
   FROM [theTable] AS t
      , (SELECT @island := 0, @lastSeqId := [somethingItCannotBe]) AS init_dnr -- Initializes variables, do not reference
   WHERE [filteringConditionsMet]
   ORDER BY [orderingCriteria]
) AS orderingQ
;
```

I tried keeping it as generic as possible, but you'll note I had to revert to the assumption that `seqId` was numeric and expected to increment by one. Conditions in the `island` calculation can be much more complicated if needed (for cases such as where `(A, 1), (A, 2), (B, 3)` should be two islands based on the sequence not being defined by a single value).

You can take this template further, to identify "island" boundaries and sizes by simple making the above query as subquery for something like:

```
SELECT island, MIN(seqId), MAX(seqId), COUNT(seqId)
FROM ([above query]) AS islandQ
GROUP BY island
;
```

Comment: Brilliant Uueerdo - my 3012 second query now takes 0.218 seconds. Your assumption was right - the source 'seqID' does increment by one. I very much appreciate your input - thank you. My up vote doesn't register as I'm too noob. +1.